# Passing parameters from Flutter to Google Cloud Functions

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to figure out how to communicate between Flutter and Google Cloud Functions.
I wrote a simple Google Cloud Function that returns a list and a parameter but I keep receiving null when I call the function with a parameter. Why is this happening?

**The Flutter Function**

```
Future<void> getFruit() async {
   HttpsCallable callable = FirebaseFunctions.instance.httpsCallable('listFruit');
   final results = await callable.call(['hello']);
   List fruit = results.data;
   print(fruit);// ["Apple", "Banana", "Cherry", "Date", "Fig", "Grapes"]
 }
```

**The Google Cloud Function**

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");

exports.listFruit = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
  return ["Apple", "Banana", "Cherry", "Date", "Fig", "Grapes", data.text];
});
```

**The Output**

```
flutter: [Apple, Banana, Cherry, Date, Fig, Grapes, null]
```

**Expected Output**

```
flutter: [Apple, Banana, Cherry, Date, Fig, Grapes, hello]
```

Can someone please help me figure out why my expected output is not coming out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

replace

```
final results = await callable.call(['hello']);
```

with

```
final results = await callable.call({text: 'hello'});
```